# Compute the sum of uniform ordered random variables

Tags: probability

> Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be independent $U(0, 1)$-distributed random variables,
>   and let $X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, X_{(3)}$ be the corresponding order variables. Compute
>   $P(X_{(1)} + X_{(3)} ≤ 1)$

What I did:

$f_{X{(1)}, X_{(3)}}(x,y)=6(y-x)$

$U=X_{(1)}+ X_{(3)}; V=X_{(3)}$ so $X_{(1)}=U-V$, where $0<u-v<v<1$ and $v<u<2v$

$f_{U,V}(u,v)=f_{X{(1)}, X_{(3)}}(u-v,v)=6(v-u+v)=-6u$; $f_U{(u)}=f_{X{(1)}, X_{(3)}}(u-v,v)dv=\int-6udv$

Here comes the difficulty:
the limits of integration. How can I detect it? It is constrained with $u=v$, and $u=2v$, so $0\le u\le2$.

When $0\le u\le1$ => $0<v\le0.5$ and when $1< u\le2$ => $0.5\le v<1$

But doing so I get $f_U{(u)}=\int_0^{0.5}-6udv=-\frac{3}{4}$, which is WRONG!

Can you give me a hint. How to compute the limits of integration?

Comment: Finding the  joint density of $(X_{(1)},X_{(3)})$ would have sufficed to calculate the probability.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Too many 'formulas' for a simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall you did a good job. But in the substitution step you made a mistake. It should be
$$
f_{U,V}(u,v) = f_{X(1),X(3)}(u-v,v) = 6(v-u+v) = 6(2v-u)
$$
and the integration is
$$
f_U(u) = \int_{u/2}^u f_{U,V}(u,v)dv = 6(v^2\vert_{u/2}^u - \frac{u^2}{2}) = \frac{3}{2}u^2.
$$